# what is the best module to use for storing geo information using postgresql and django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, geolocation

I am developing a project in which at some point I have the requirements like this:

1. I need to store the city, state, province, zipcode from the address in separate database fields.
2. This should be used to query based on the city or state or zipcode.
3. I need to find the locations based on the given zipcode and the distance from the zipcode given.

What is the best module that can be used that supports the above requirements. I have used Geopy but I think its not that good to store the data.What if I use PostGIS? I was struck at this point and not able to decide what to use! what is the best way to handle this kind of data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to have a look at [GeoDjango](http://geodjango.org/). It's a collection of components that add geographic support to Django, it has first-class support for Django's models API and can leverage any spatial database your application is using.

You can check out the [Database API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#) to get an idea of the kinds of queryies you'll be able to perform with the GeoDjango model queryset.